# Ошибка "Access violation at address" при работе с ассемблером (mov) в Делфи

Tags: delphi, ассемблер

*Перегружал Delphi 10.2 и Windows 10, но ошибки всё те же. Asm плохо знаю только учусь :)*

**1)**

```
procedure u(a: cardinal);assembler;
asm
  mov r15, [a]
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  u(5);
end;
```

Ставлю на точка останова на асм, перехожу на **FreeMemoryContexts**

```
unit Vcl.Controls;

procedure TWinControl.MainWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  try
    try
      WindowProc(Message);
    finally
      FreeDeviceContexts;
      FreeMemoryContexts;
    end;
  except
    Application.HandleException(Self);
  end;
end;
```

А Дальше Access violation at address.
Если поменять в процедуре параметр, что бы был 64 битный procedure u(a: Int64) ошибка та же, так что дело не в размерности параметра и регистра.

---

**2)** Продолжаем эксперимент:

```
procedure u;assembler;
asm
  mov rcx, 3
 @N: nop
  loop @N
  nop
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  u;
end;
```

В дельфи галочка Оптимизация не стоит, ставлю точку останова в процедуре асм, но не циклит трижды, а проходит 1 раз, потом обнуляет регистр `rcx` и выходит запросто, тут хоть без ошибок. Работает, без цикла, что с пустыми командами (`nop`), что с любыми другими.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы пытаетесь загрузить содержимое памяти по адресу в переменной `a`, а не саму переменную `a`. Правильно так:

   ```
   procedure u(a: int64); assembler; // заметьте, что я сменил тип переменной!!!
   asm
      mov r15, a 
   end;
   ```
2. Всё правильно, "циклить" в вашем понимании и не должно, это не `for` на языке высокого уровня (хотя и `for` при хорошей оптимизации можно свести к `loop`), перейдите в режим машинных команд, чтобы было проще понять. А для проверки можно использовать, к примеру, такой код:

   ```
   procedure u;assembler;
   asm
     mov rax, 1
     mov rcx, 3
     @N: shl rax, 1
     loop @N
   end;
   ```

В регистре RAX на выходе будет 8, наш цикл успешно состоялся.

Comment: Узнал, что просто "asm loop" через F8 не работает, сразу весь цикл без итераций видимых, нужно через F7 тогда зайдет внутрь, так что это был кажущийся вход в цикл единожды, на самом деле нет он прошел трижды

Answer (score 1):

```
mov r15, [a]
```

Эта строчка копирует в регистр то, что лежит по **адресу**, хранящемуся в a.

```
u(5);
```

Таким образом, происходит обращение к адресу `$0000000000000005`, который не относится к адресному пространству программы (это вообще защитный диапазон адресов Windows). AV при этом обязано происходить.

Для использования **числа** 5 нужно убрать квадратные скобки

По второму вопросу - нет смысла обсуждать бессмысленный код. Сделайте хотя бы функцию и вставьте

```
 xor rax, rax
 ...
 inc eax //в цикле
```